# ASP.NET Web API: Use the default serializer

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Is there a simple way to use ASP.NET Web API's default serializer?

Mine is configured in that fashion in WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

It works perfectly. What I would like to do is use the very same serializer manually in a specific situation. If for some reason that config changes, the manual serialization must reflect those changes without having to care about it.

To be more precise about my intentions, I want to send new resources to a SignalR Hub just after they've been saved to the database. They need to be serialized in the same exact way that ASP.NET Web API does when using a GET request.

Comment: i am not clear on this part: "use the very same serializer manually in a specific situation". As per above details, you are having settings on the global formatter. regarding "send new resources to a SignalR Hub", how are you doing this? (like do you use httpclient and are you trying to use json formatter)..sorry for lot of questions..

Comment: No matter how, if someone POSTs a resource, it needs to be broadcasted to every SignalR user that needs to be kept updated in a live fashion. This process must use the same serialization configuration that Web API does at all times.

Comment: ok. client1(posts resource) -> service(broadcasts) -> client2, client3, clientn. In this setup the service is a webapi having the serializer settings you mentioned above. since the settings are on global formatter, when the resource is broadcasted to client2 and client3, they should be using the same global formatter settings...am i thinking in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on this bug report: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/500

First, create a custom IContractResolver

```
public class SignalRContractResolver : IContractResolver
{
    private readonly Assembly _assembly;
    private readonly IContractResolver _camelCaseContractResolver;
    private readonly IContractResolver _defaultContractSerializer;

    public SignalRContractResolver()
    {
        _defaultContractSerializer = new DefaultContractResolver();
        _camelCaseContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        _assembly = typeof(Connection).Assembly;
    }

    public JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        if (type.Assembly.Equals(_assembly))
            return _defaultContractSerializer.ResolveContract(type);

        return _camelCaseContractResolver.ResolveContract(type);
    }
}
```

Next, register it in ApplicationStart

```
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    settings.ContractResolver = new SignalRContractResolver();

    var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer(settings);

    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IJsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```

Thanks to halter73 for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: what is Connection in the line "assembly = typeof(Connection).Assembly;
". I don't find it

Answer (score 0):

You can register your own `IJsonSerializer` with SignalR's dependency resolver at application start using your custom JSON.NET serializer settings.

```
//...
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//...

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer(settings);

        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IJsonSerializer), () => serializer);

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

        //...
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach... At the moment, if I comment this block (excluding MapHubs) it outputs data in Pascal Case. As soon as I uncomment it, the client side completely stops receiving events.

Comment: I found out that the problem comes from the ContractResolver setting. Just by commenting this line, the system works, but still in PascalCase obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it's works fine

```
var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
formatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```

This is must be placed in "Global.asax.cs" file in "Application_Start" function